# Match values of radio button selections to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a few radio button groups, depending on which radio button is selected in each group, that particular answer needs to return 1 or more values which are preset in an array.

So, if 1 is selected in group 1, A & B values both increment by 1, If 2 is selected B, C & D increment and so on. At the end the letter with most points/increments should be returned (when the form is submitted)

How can I get going with this? I think the starting point is to return the selected radio buttons, match them to the correct array index, then check for the values in that array (letters) with the most increments and return it's value(s)?

```
  $(function(){

    var group1 = new Array();
      group1[0] = "A, B";
      group1[1] = "B, C, D";
      group1[2] = "E, B";
      group1[3] = "B";
      group1[4] = "F";

    var group2 = new Array();
      group2[0] = "D, A";
      group2[1] = "D, C";
      group2[2] = "B, F, E";
      group2[3] = "A";
      group2[4] = "B, D";

    $('form').submit(function(){

      var checked = $('input:radio:checked').length;

      //This is as far as I am

    });

    });

    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" id="q1-1" /> 1
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" id="q1-2" /> 2
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" id="q1-3" /> 3
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" id="q1-4" /> 4
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" id="q1-5" /> 5

      <br /><br />

      <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1" id="q2-1" /> 1
      <input type="radio" name="group2" value="2" id="q2-2" /> 2
      <input type="radio" name="group2" value="3" id="q2-3" /> 3
      <input type="radio" name="group2" value="4" id="q2-4" /> 4
      <input type="radio" name="group2" value="5" id="q2-5" /> 5

      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with it will give you result as you created array so i used switch to select the values from array.

```
var temp=0;
var result = [];
var maxvalue = 0;
var topQualityjob = "";
    $('input:radio:checked').each(function () {
        switch ($(this).attr("name")) {
            case "group1":
                $(group1[parseInt($(this).val()) - 1].split(",")).each(function () {
                    result.push(this);
                    temp = getaccurance(result, this);
                    if (maxvalue < temp) {
                        maxvalue = temp;
                        topQualityjob = this;
                    }
                });
                break;
            case "group2":
                $(group2[parseInt($(this).val()) - 1].split(",")).each(function () {
                    result.push(this);
                    temp = getaccurance(result, this);
                    if (maxvalue < temp) {
                        maxvalue = temp;
                        topQualityjob = this;
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    });
    alert(topQualityjob);
```

}

```
function getaccurance(result, val) {
    num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] == val)
            num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Hope this will give correct answer

Comment: Thanks Meraj, I think I'm almost there but I still haven't quite got it yet. I've put the updated script on js fiddle, I still can't get the result variable to increment, but I'm sure I'll get it if I play around a bit more. http://jsfiddle.net/hANsE/4/